# Using git to make daily snapshots of a mirror

Tags: git, snapshot, mirror

I'd like to mirror a remote site (something like CPAN, via rsync) and create daily snapshots with `git`. Is there any tool that does the "remove the deleted files from the repository and add the changed/new files to the index and commit with the current date as the commit message" task?

The idea is to make an archive of the site (files only) and go back in time day by day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a shell script:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "changes on `date`"
```

not sure if it makes sense to put current date into a commit message, because each commit has timestamp anyway already.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick! The date is optional of course, but as I want to do the mirroring and commit from a script, anything would be fine.